# ¿Todas las vistas tienen un contexto en Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Estaba haciendo un curso de Kotlin y me ha surgido esta duda: **¿todas las vistas tienen un contexto?** Puede que sea por la falta de conocimientos en entender bien y de forma "simple" que es el contexto en una app de Android.

Por ejemplo se que en un Adapter cuando queremos acceder al contexto podemos acceder a este a traves del holder que nos proporciona el método onBindViewHolder, pero, ¿cual es la diferencia de obtenerlo a través del propio itemView que puede recibir la clase ViewHolder que creamos en el Adapter? O la diferencia de obtenerlo a través de un setOnClickListener que le hacemos a un botón.

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    private val mediaItemTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mediaTitle)
    private val mediaItemImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mediaThumb)

    fun bind(mediaItem: MediaItem) {
        mediaItemTitle.text = mediaItem.title
        mediaItemImage.loadUrl(mediaItem.imageUrl)

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            itemView.context.toast(mediaItem.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Después me surge otra pregunta: **¿todos los componentes de una vista tienen un contexto?** Un ImageView, un TextView, **¿y una CustomView que llamamos en nuestra vista también?**

¿Que formas hay de llamar al contexto y cuales son las más seguras sin riesgo de que obtengamos un leak. Una forma fácil de obtener un contexto en un adapter sería pasarle por constructor el contexto de la activity o fragment donde vamos a usarlo, pero se que esto causaría un memory leak. A ver si me podéis ayudar un poco ya que quiero tomar nota de estos casos para saber cual sería la forma más óptima en cada caso posible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, todas las vistas tienen un contexto.

Fíjate en su constructores, por ejemplo de un ImageView:

```
 public AppCompatImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AppCompatImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AppCompatImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
```

Los ViewGrups extienden de View por lo que también tienen un context.

Intenta evitar pasar el contexto a un adapter porque realmente no te hace falta, lo que hay que cambiar es el enfoque que estás siguiendo.  Por ejemplo, un adapter lo que hace es de puente entre la vista y el ViewHolder,y el ViewHolder es la celda que va a hacer el populate del item y también capturar los clicks.  Pero ojo, capturar el click no quiere decir implementar ningún comportamiento.  El comportamiento lo implementará la Activity/Fragment, por ejemplo, para mostrar un Toast, navegación, gestión de permisos... siempre respetando la arquitectura que estás utilizando. Para esto puedes emplear un callback (interfaz) o una lambda, en Kotlin es una higher order function.

Comment: Me ha servido la verdad, solo una pregunta: que es el populate? Quizás sea otra forma de llamar a algo que ya conozco pero no me suena ahora mismo :)

Comment: Sí, hacer un populate es poblar una vista, es decir, setear sus valores. Tú le has llamado bind.  Para mí ese nombre no es correcto porque bindear es enlazar, por ejemplo el fndViewById es un bind.

Comment: ¿Y que nombre le pondrías tu a ese método?

Comment: populate().  Y el listener evita hacerlo ahí porque siempre que se setean los valores también estás seteando el listener y no hace falta.  Setéalo en el init de Kotlin (costructor)